# Yet another Java events question

Tags: java, android, events, design-patterns

So I have seen multiple questions on stackoverflow asking how to implement events in java but not a single one seems to provide examples other then "read this".

Could someone please be kind enough to provide a succinct example of how one could implement the basic equivalent of the following C# code?

```
public event EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs> MessageReceived;
protected virtual void OnMessageReceived(Socket socket, CommandType commandType, MemoryStream message) 
{
    if (this.MessageReceived != null)
    {
        this.MessageReceived(this, new MessageReceivedEventArgs(socket, commandType, message));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually multi-cast delegates aren't used in Java. If you don't need multi-casting, then the code will be like this:

```
public interface MessageReceivedListener {
    void onMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e);
}

private MessageReceivedListener messageReceivedListener;

public void setMessageReceivedListener(MessageReceivedListener listener) {
    this.messageReceivedListener = listener;
}

protected void onMessageReceived(Socket socket, CommandType commandType, MemoryStream message) {
    if (this.messageReceivedListener != null) {
        this.messageReceivedListener.onMessageReceived(this,
           new MessageReceivedEventArgs(socket, commandType, message));
    }
}
```

If you want to implement multi-casting, then you can create a container with listeners, iterate through these listeners and call handlers. In this case there'll be `addMessageReceivedListener` and `removeMessageReceivedListener` methods for managing active listeners.